# Similar tags [android-jetpack] [android-architecture-components] [androidx]

Tags: support, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

Tags [android-jetpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack) [android-architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-components) [androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidx) are similar to same degree.

- [Android Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack)
  is the most prominent term, often being used synonym to AndroidX.
- [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture) namespace  [`android.arch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/packages) had been deprecated.
- [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) is the current namespace; see [class mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings#androidarch) `android.arch` to `androidx.arch`.

a) [android-architecture-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-components) probably should be merged into [android-jetpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack) or [androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidx).

b) [android-jetpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack) and [androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/androidx) could be merged; but this would require a closer review.